# Has physics ever given a physical significance to a mathematically abstract idea?

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-physics

Consider a fundamental concept in maths that was created to 'solve' a problem that simply couldn't be solved by any other approach (or maybe for some other reason). Now let's assume that this concept made no sense to the contemporary mathematicians whatsoever that they simply brushed it aside as a purely mathematical tool with $0$ physical significance. *like the square root of $-1
, $ $ i$ or the Euler number maybe?*. Anything that makes no sense to a present-day mathematical outsider really.

A couple of decades later after its birth, baam, a scientist realises that the only way to solve a paradox in physics was to use this very mathematical concept that had to seem to be abstract at the time. Is there any good example of this in history?

---

Inspiration

This is with respect to [the idea of maths being seen as a subject](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/response-to-students-who-say-this-is-not-important) with no real-life application. I wanted to disprove by saying that many mathematical concepts do have a real-life application (if we look back at the history), but it's just that we haven't found any use so far.

I am slightly aware that e and [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) like $i$ makes it into the world of electrical engineering though I don't remember where exactly. I also vaguely recollect topology space and an array of mathematical concepts coming into the world by the theory of [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) and [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics). What I am really looking for is

(1) a concept in maths that initially seems to have had no use 
(2) 70 years later it is been used in a formula (please do add the formula too; that's really the reason I came here)

Comment: Gromov-Witten invariant.

Comment: @MarkSapir: More precisely, Schubert calculus, which was a predecessor of GW invariants (by about 80-90 years).

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Schubert calculus has very little to do with it.

Comment: @MarkSapir: It is like saying that Dehn's algorithm for surface groups has very little to do with hyperbolic groups. Take a look for instance at the article [Quantum Schubert Calculus](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870897916273) by Bertram.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Yes, Dehn algorithm has very little to do with hyperbolic groups too.

Comment: I should also add this in the comments in case it was missed out, but is there any formula in physics that uses $i$, the iota?

Comment: George Boole invented an algebra for logic that is now the foundation of our modern world (e.g. the computer I am entering this on, etc).  https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_Boole

Comment: @JosephDoggie Boole is actually the winner in my opinion. When Boole first presented his work on the subject he introduced it by saying, "I give you a fascinating system that has absolutely no application." [Source](http://example.com)

Comment: I was looking for that quote, but couldn't find it.  Thanks

Comment: It's not clear that this topic will dispell the notions of the students in the other question. Students who don't like math probably also don't like science classes, either.

Comment: Imaginary numbers, transcendental *e*, tensors, quaternions, group theory, non-Euclidian geometry etc. etc.

Comment: [A sketch with e, i, π, and β](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKq6_vjrxMo).

Comment: Since you asked... Complex numbers are used in  _Fourier_ analysis.  They greatly simplify analyzing the _frequency domain_ by representing it has having two signals, a real part and an imaginary part.  In electrical engineering, the imaginary part is typically represented by _j_ (and not by the _i_ you learned in high school).  The first link I found: http://dspguide.com/ch30.htm

Comment: Let's not forget the Hilbert space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Physics found that 1+2+3+4+... = -1/12 in 1918.  This later showed up in String theory around 2003ish.

Comment: *This later showed up in Bosonic String theory in the late 1960s.

Comment: How about group theory used to solve Rubik's Cube?   :-)

Comment: You brought up imaginary numbers, but that itself is a good example isn't it? It started as a mathematical abstraction, but in QM it's (arguably) a concept of fundamental importance. (Arguably because I think some people think there are ways of making the same computations without imaginary numbers).

Comment: @TKoL exactly i am searching for that equation which uses the imaginary number... but without any luck

Comment: @AdilMohammed I'm no expert, but the example I know of in QM that uses imaginary numbers is, I believe, how the amplitude changes as a photon gets bounced off a silver / half-silvered mirror (or beam splitter).

Comment: See also https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7731/229

Comment: Euler's formula:  exp(i * theta) = cos(theta) + i * sin (theta) -- j for EE's  see:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Typically, in polar coordinates, the magnitude (complex version of absolute value) of a complex quantity represents amplitude or intensity (sometimes used to calculate power, which is usually proportional to magnitude squared) and the angle is the phase, which is related to delay in a time-wave or (more generally) an offset -- see also:  https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/complex-numbers.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Physics cannot help giving physical significance to things. But, yes, the *first* item on your list should have been

- [Lie Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#History).

Developed as a mathematical "sudoku" game generalizing rotations, in the late 19th century, by Sophus Lie, Felix Klein, Friedrich Engel, Henri Poincare, and, as  associated  applied mathematical structures by James Joseph Sylvester and Arthur Cayley,
they were recognized by physicists in the early 20th century to apply to the new-fangled science of [Quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics), the actual cornerstone of modern physics, by Eugene Wigner and Hermann Weyl, firstly through the rotation group SO(3) ~ SU(2).

In the 1960s, Murray Gell-Mann appreciated that SU(3), both classified and further described, in fact, elementary particle interactions, the [Eightfold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)); whence  the full-fledged Lie Group theory entered as *the* mainstay of Quantum Field Theory describing fundamental particles and forces in *all* of High Energy physics. Now *that's* an example of abstract math underlying all of nature at its most fundamental, a century before that was recognized!

Today, hardly anything describing electroweak interactions, strong interactions, or gravity is thinkable without crucial and *irreplaceable* reliance on [Lie Group representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics_and_representation_theory). ***The fundamental laws of nature run on Lie groups***. Theoretical HEP theorists are part-time Lie-Group applied mathematicians. [This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is the sort of thing they have to master in school.

Comment: Well,  not first in historical order!  :-) .

Comment: It *might* be though that the assumed mathematics of symmetry breaking is not there (in the field of high energies). It might turn out that the weak force is a residual force. And the Higg field a normal field (with no associated false vacuum), thereby *not* providing a mass for all massive particles. It might be that there are more fundamental massless particles, giving rise to massive particles (because of their interaction in a bound state) and a residual weak force. Eventhough the math of the electroweak unification is impressive, this doesn't mean that it corresponds to reality.

Comment: This is not to say that "Lie math" is of great value. I'm not sure if you can say that high-energy stuff has an inherent mathematical structure though. The stuff it real, but the math? In general relativity, spacetime has mathematical properties  and math structures can be imposed, but are they real existing in spacetime? The spacetime is real (as elementary particles), but is the math inherent to (for?) spacetime?

Answer (score 21):

**fractal**

The so-called Cantor set was described by
**Georg Cantor**, 1884 (or **H. J. S. Smith**, 1875?)
Sets with "fractional" dimension were described by
**Felix Hausdorff**, 1918
Investigated thoroughly by
**A. S. Besicovitch**, 1930s - 1950s
But these were only mathematical abstractions.

**Benoit B. Mandelbrot**, 1960s and later
claimed relevance of these sets in natural sciences.
Mandelbrot reported that, in the early days, when he would submit a paper
to a physics journal with a Cantor set in it, that it would be rejected out-of-hand as "unphysical".

Largely due to Mandelbrot's efforts, that situation has been completely reversed.
In 1992, I counted that physics papers with the word "fractal" in the title were appearing more frequently than once a week.

Answer (score 18):

The following quote is from [C. N. Yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Chen-Ning), delivered at a 1979 symposium dedicated to the geometer [Chern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiing-Shen_Chern): "*When I met Chern, I told him that I finally understood the beauty of the theory of fibre bundles and the elegant Chern​–Weil theorem.  I was struck that gauge fields, in particular connections on fibre bundles, were studied by mathematicians without any appeal to physical realities.  I added that it is mysterious and incomprehensible how you mathematicians could think this up out of nothing.  To this Chern immediately objected. 'No, no, this concept is not invented — it is natural and real*.'"

Comment: That is true. Also the concept of "reality" is one of the most difficult concepts in philosophy.

Answer (score 8):

Abelian and non-abelian group theory -> quantum chromodynamics

Noneuclidean geometry -> general relativity

Sorry, I cannot write you any equations as examples.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this can be counted for as physics, but to my knowledge the radon transformation was mostly something mathematicians thought about without any application. Now, it is widely used (and necessary) to transform images in tomography.

1917 - Radon transform introduced by Johann Radon

1970s - First Computer Tomograph Scan

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform

Answer (score 6):

There are many examples of a physical significance given to abstract mathematical ideas.
One of the most prominent is the spacetime as introduced in general relativity. In general relativity a mathematical framework is given that informs you about the structure of space. It even relates space with time, thereby introducing new physical stuff, i.e., spacetime. The theory is inspired by real physical things (space and time) but the extra quality that came up was a connection between those two, given by the math. Matter and energy already existed before the theory but general relativity proposed a connection between these and the new kind of spacetime that it introduced. This connection was absent in the earlier theory of Newton who said that space and time are not connected and are not influenced by the matter and energy that is contained in space.
New things like spacetime curvature, an absolute limit on speed (which actually gave rise to the concept of relativity), the equivalence of mass and energy, etc., were introduced as mathematical expressions, changing the physical aspects of the universe.
Einstein, for formulating his ideas, made use of in his time already existing mathematical ideas introduced by mathematicians like Riemann, Ricci, Levi-Civita, and Killing.
New discoveries were made, inspired by Einstein's ideas. Though physical things like space and time already existed, the mathematics of Riemannian manifolds was used to make a connection between them, thereby postulating the new physical entity, i.e., spacetime.
So, a physical significance was indeed given to the ideas of real manifolds and tensor calculus.

Answer (score 6):

Riemann geometry: Einstein had to look around for the mathematics that could describe General Relativity. Before that nobody would have guessed that curved geometry has anything to do with space-time and gravity.

Answer (score 5):

I think one of the best example is the binary system, the representing of numbers in 0 and 1 by diving them by 2. This is how every processor, ram, HDD, SSD,.. etc keep data and how digital communications work. Also the whole Boole algebra is the basics of how computer processors calculate numbers.

> In 1605 Francis Bacon discussed a system whereby letters of the
> alphabet could be reduced to sequences of binary digits, which could
> then be encoded as scarcely visible variations in the font in any
> random text.[16] Importantly for the general theory of binary
> encoding, he added that this method could be used with any objects at
> all: "provided those objects be capable of a twofold difference only;
> as by Bells, by Trumpets, by Lights and Torches, by the report of
> Muskets, and any instruments of like nature".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: See also George Boole's contribution with Boolean Algebra, and its notation.

Answer (score 4):

Spinors were introduced by E.Cartan and found applications in quantum theory 15 years later.

Answer (score 2):

The most striking examples are the special and general relativity theories. Einstein gave physical meaning to abstract ideas of Riemann, Poincare, Lorenz, Lie and others.

Answer (score 1):

Not really physics, but: I think that number theory (edit: specifically research on primes) was an entirely idle mathematical pastime until cryptography became a thing.

Comment: That is not true, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory#Applications

Comment: @MarkSapir You mean "Thank God that number theory is unsullied by any application"? OK; that changed in the middle of the 20th century, so maybe before cryptography but with the advent of computers. And computer based cryptography is still one of the main applications.

Comment: Physicists would disagree. Antient astronomers would be insulted too. You are safe insulting them now: they are long dead.

Comment: Yes, crypto is a thing. But/and the modern (post 1945?) significance of representation theory and functional analysis in the theory of automorphic forms, etc., has been intertwined-with, and both motivated by and motivating, various parts of physics. A big story...

Comment: Cryptography doesn't have physical reality in terms of describing physical systems.  Information theory in general has connections to thermodynamics, but your answer is going to need to be more specific to work as an answer to the question of "**physical** significance".  That's different from "practical applications".

Comment: Cryptography most certainly does have relevance to physical systems. Number theory was crucial to the design of the Enigma machine used by the Axis powers in WW2 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine#Mathematical_analysis) and to the design of the electro-mechanical "bombe" device Alan Turing designed to crack it (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe#The_principle_of_the_bombe)